# Using ag-grid correctly

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is it possible to use Ag-Grid javascript version with ASP.Net MVC Application,
If So, Please tell me how to use.

I tried the demo given in ag-grid site, [AG-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started/).

But it is not working fine with asp.net, I am getting Error says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
at e.getTheme (ag-grid.min.js:242)
at e.specialForNewMaterial (ag-grid.min.js:20)
at e.getHeaderHeight (ag-grid.min.js:20)
at e.getGroupHeaderHeight (ag-grid.min.js:20)
at t.setBodyAndHeaderHeights (ag-grid.min.js:74)
at t.init (ag-grid.min.js:74)
at ag-grid.min.js:8
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ag-grid.min.js:8
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I doubt if I am missing any other packages.

```js
 var rowData = [
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
    ];

    var columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
    { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
    { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }
    ];

    
    function doProcess() {
        var gridOptions = {
            rowData: rowData,
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            onGridReady: function (params) {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
        };
        new agGrid.Grid("#myGrid", gridOptions);
    }

    doProcess();
```

```html
<!-- Inside the view page -->

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.noStyle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@17.0.0/dist/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 131px; width:600px;" ></div>
```

Comment: code please, presumably if you tried to follow a demo but something went wrong, then maybe you missed something or didn't configure properly. But just from the error message, we can't tell for sure. The error seems to be in a method relating to themes, so possibly you got some setting wrong, or forgot some CSS or some extra JS, who knows. Also, hard to see how this really relates to MVC, since it appears to be an entirely client-side plugin. I doubt that MVC is really the problematic factor here.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited. please check it out now.

Comment: See my answer below. Removed the MVC tag because, as I predicted, it's nothing whatsoever to do with MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the blog shows that only `ag-grid.min.noStyle.js` is loaded in that demo, whereas you have loaded `ag-grid.min.js` as well. I would guess they are variants of the same thing, and this is almost certainly unnecessary. Also there is no apparent need for jQuery.

Lastly though, and most importantly, you created your grid like this:

```
new agGrid.Grid("#myGrid", gridOptions);
```

by passing in a selector string directly. However the demo (and no doubt the documentation, if you check it) clearly shows that a DOM element is passed in, created by using document.querySelector, i.e.

```
var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
        new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
```

Since you passed the grid something it didn't understand, it can't load anything into it.

Working demo:

```js
var rowData = [
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
    ];

    var columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
    { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
    { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }
    ];

    
    function doProcess() {
        var gridOptions = {
            rowData: rowData,
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            onGridReady: function (params) {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
        };
        var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
        new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
    }

    doProcess();
```

```html
<!-- Inside the view page -->

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@17.0.0/dist/ag-grid.min.noStyle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 131px; width:600px;" ></div>
```

N.B. If you're going to follow a demo, it's usually wise to follow it accurately, and only change things where you understand the consequences and actually need to change them to fulfil your own project's requirement. In the case of the changes you have made, most of them look unnecessary, including the one which caused the problem.

Comment: I ran code snippet over here, Still grid not loaded. I added ag-grid.min.noStyle.js and other CSS's  only when the exact code in demo failed to load grid.

Comment: do you get a console error or anything? BTW If you ran exactly the code I gave above, it would work. It works when it is run within this answer (just press Run Code Snippet above, the grid does take a couple of seconds before it renders, seems to be a slow plugin) Clearly, if it doesn't work for you, then either something else is interfering, or you haven't copied all the details correctly. As you can see by running it here, what I've written works. You just need to play spot the difference between that and your version.

Comment: Also the "exact code from the demo" works perfectly - I pasted it here: https://jsfiddle.net/n3g43nbh/ and it executes. So again, if it didn't work for you I suspect you did not in fact implement it correctly. All you have to do is copy and paste...well obviously if you're trying to put it into an MVC View it's not quite that simple, but it's not going to be much more work than that.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. problem is in javascript binding line, Query selector.